# Trigger para atualizar um campo automaticamente após o insert

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Tenho uma tabela de usuário, basicamente:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sistema`.`user` (
  `id_user` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `hashed_id` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `nome` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `cpf` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  UNIQUE INDEX `hashed_id_UNIQUE` (`hashed_id` ASC)  COMMENT '',
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Quero criar uma `trigger` para quando for criado um novo usuário, o `hashed_id` sejá atualizado com um código de 12 números ou letras, e ainda tenho que garantir que esse `hash` sejá único, enquanto não for, gerar outro.

Seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `sistema`.`teste_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE
INSERT
ON
  `teste` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT
  @lid := LAST_INSERT_ID();
UPDATE
  `sistema`.`teste`
SET
  hashed_id = CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING(
      'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789',
      RAND(
        @seed := ROUND(RAND(@lid) * 4294967296)
      ) * 36 + 1,
      1
    ),
    SUBSTRING(
      'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789',
      RAND(
        @seed := ROUND(RAND(@seed) * 4294967296)
      ) * 36 + 1,
      1
    ),
    SUBSTRING(
      'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789',
      RAND(
        @seed := ROUND(RAND(@seed) * 4294967296)
      ) * 36 + 1,
      1
    ),
    SUBSTRING(
      'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789',
      RAND(
        @seed := ROUND(RAND(@seed) * 4294967296)
      ) * 36 + 1,
      1
    ),
    SUBSTRING(
      'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789',
      RAND(
        @seed := ROUND(RAND(@seed) * 4294967296)
      ) * 36 + 1,
      1
    ),
    SUBSTRING(
      'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789',
      RAND(
        @seed := ROUND(RAND(@seed) * 4294967296)
      ) * 36 + 1,
      1
    ),
    SUBSTRING(
      'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789',
      RAND(
        @seed := ROUND(RAND(@seed) * 4294967296)
      ) * 36 + 1,
      1
    ),
    SUBSTRING(
      'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789',
      RAND(@seed) * 36 + 1,
      1
    )
  )
WHERE
  id = @lid;
  END
```

Esse esquema de `trigger` é [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16738409/3956218)

Comment: 12 caracteres com 36 opções geram 4.738.381.338.321.616.896 combinações , se o algoritmo de geração for aleatório a chance de colisão é quase zero.bast a função para gerar a sequencia aleatoria.

Comment: Esse é um problema "é quase zero", tem que ser zero! Claro enquanto o número de combinações possivel for menor que a quantidade de users registrados.

Comment: O segundo problema está na trigger que não está correta :( nunca trabalhei com triggers, então não sei monta-la

Comment: É mais fácil acertar na Loto que obter um conflito , não conheço a  síntaxe de MySql mas faria uma function para gerar a string , todavia veja este tópico do SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737910/generating-a-random-unique-8-character-string-using-mysql  do Paul Spiegel